# Open file from isolatedstorage in default app (Windows Phone 8)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage, isolatedstoragefile

I have a question about opening a file stored in IsolatedStorage in my Windows Phone 8 C# app (in my case a file.txt file)
and opening it up in Office suite integrated in WP 8.

I have come up with this:

```
 Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new System.Uri("ms-word:" + (new Uri("file.txt", UriKind.Relative))));
```

It opens up Office Word with no problem, but it hangs at the "file does not exists" message and quits..
Any advice ? Thanks :)

Comment: I'm taking a not so wild guess, that you can't open non-office files with word.

Comment: Well, wrong guess. http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp7/office/office-mobile-faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Uri is wrong. It should be `new Uri("ms-word:isostore:file.txt", UriKind.Absolute);`
But still, the file can't be opened. Don't know why.

[image]

**EDIT**: This is not possible. You can only open office email attachments or office documents from OneDrive.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wppersonal/open-word-and-excel-files-from-sd-card/23218c41-b72b-49df-9529-5e85a1912bc5

Comment: Yeah actually I come to that too. It even does that when i try to open docx file...Im lost right now :( still thanks a lot :)